# What is the autocovariance of $y_t = \exp{(x_t)}$ where $x_t$ is a stationary normal process.

Tags: statistics, means, moment-generating-functions, time-series, gaussian

> Let $x_t$ be a stationary normal process with mean $\mu_x$ and
> autocovariance function $\gamma(h)$. Define the nonlinear time series
> $y_t=\exp{(x_t)}$.
>
> (a) Express the mean function $E(y_t)$ in terms of $\mu_x$ and
> $\gamma(0)$. The moment generating function of a normal random
> variable $x$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ is
>
> $$M_x(\lambda)=E[\exp{(\lambda x)}]=\exp{(\mu \lambda +
> > \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \lambda^2})$$
>
> (b) Determine the autocovariance function of $y_t$. The sum of the two
> normal randomvariables $x_{t+h}+x_t$ is still a normal random
> variable.

EDIT:
I figured out the first part, but still struggling with part b.

First we not the MGF for a normal rv $x$ with mean $\mu_x$ and variance $\sigma_x^2$ is
$$E[\exp(xt)] = \exp\left[\mu_x t + \frac{\sigma_x^2 t^2}{2}\right]$$

so that $E[y_t] = E[\exp(x_t)]$ is the same as the normal MGF evaluated at $t=1$, which implies that the mean function of $y_t$ is

$$E[y_t] = E[\exp(x_t)]= \exp\left[\mu_x + \frac{\gamma_x(0)}{2}\right]$$

EDIT 5:  I think I finally see where the dependence of $x_t$ plays in.  How is this?

Note that since $x_t$ and $x_{t+h}$ are identically distributed normal but not independent then the mean and variance of $x_t+x_{t+h}$ are

$$\mu_{x_t+x_{t+h}} = 2\mu_x$$

$$\sigma^2_{x_t+x_{t+h}} = \gamma_x(0) + \gamma_x(0) + 2\rho_x(h)\gamma_x(0) = 2\gamma_x(0)(1+\rho_x(h))$$

Thus the MGF for $x_t+x_{t+h}$ is

$$M_{x_t+x_{t+h}}(\lambda) = E[\exp(\lambda(x_t+x_{t+h}))] = \exp\left[2\mu_x \lambda + \gamma_x(0)(1+\rho_x(h))\lambda^2]\right]$$

By the same argument above using the MGF evaluated at $\lambda = 1$ we have

$$E[y_ty_{t+h}] = E[\exp(x_t+x_{t+h})] = M_{x_t+x_{t+h}}(1) = \exp\left[2\mu_x + \gamma_x(0)(1+\rho_x(h))]\right]$$
And we can calculate the autocovariance:

$$\gamma_y(h) = E[y_ty_{t+h}] - \mu_y^2 = \exp[2\mu_x + \gamma_x(0) + \gamma_x(0)\rho_x(h)] - \exp[2\mu_x +\gamma_x(0)]$$

$$=\exp[2\mu_x + \gamma_x(0)]\exp[\gamma_x(0)\rho_x(h)] - \exp[2\mu_x + \gamma_x(0)]$$

$$=\exp[2\mu_x + \gamma_x(0)]\left(\exp[\gamma_x(0)\rho_x(h)] - 1\right)$$

Comment: $E(y_ty_{t+h})$ is a function of $h$, but not of $t$, since it stationary.

Comment: I came to the conclusion that the autocovariance is 0.  Is that right?

Comment: I realized that my actual mistake was not squaring the coefficient for the variance in the MGF.  If I do this then I believe I get the correct answer,  I created a 4th edit with the solution.  I also added a complete solution below which might be easier to understand without all the fumbling around above.

Comment: In the above there is a new symbol $M_{(x_t+x_{t+h})}(2)$.  In the answer below you still do do have $\gamma_x(h)$ so it can't be right.  I've revised my solution, shifting the mean - it is much simpler, so you might try the final step.

Comment: $M(\lambda)$ is the MGF as stated in the problem and solution.  Also, I am not looking for $\gamma_x(h)$.  I am looking for $\gamma_y(h)$ which is in the solution.

Comment: $\gamma_y(h)$ must be a function of $\gamma_x(h)$.It does not show up in your solution.

Comment: It doesn't have to be. I'm pretty sure that it is independent of $h$, which makes sense to me, because the series is in no way based on a lag, so at each $t$ no matter the lag, the autocovariance is the covariance between 2 identical log normal rv and thus is just the variance of the log normal distribution.

Comment: If you look at my answer you will see the dependence on $\gamma_x(h)$.  " series is in no way based on a lag," is irrelevant.  You are getting function of two points in the series, so it depends on separation.

Comment: I think I finally see what you are saying.  Added a new solution under Edit 5.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong! $E(exp(x_t+x_{t+h}))$ is not $E(x_t)^2$.  You need to take into account the autocorrelation., since they are not independent.

Formula for $A=E(exp(x_t+x_{t+h}))$:  To save writing, simplify notation.  $w=x_t-\mu$, $y=x_{t+h}-\mu$, $\rho=\gamma(h)/\gamma(0)$ = auto-correlation, $\alpha=\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$.

$A=\frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2 \alpha}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^Kdwdy$ where $K=2\mu+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2 \alpha^2}(2\sigma^2 \alpha^2(w+y)-w^2+2\rho wy-y^2)$

The variables can be decoupled by $b=w+y$ and $c=w-y$ so that:

$K=2\mu+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2 \alpha^2}(2\sigma^2 \alpha^2 b-\frac{b^2+c^2}{2}+\rho\frac{b^2-c^2}{2})$

and $dwdy=\frac{1}{2}dbdc$

I'll let you do the calculation using the product of two normal distributions.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific.  I don't see it.

Comment: Are you trying to say that $E(y_t^2)$ is not $E(\exp(x_t+x_{t+h}))$?  Because I did not suggest $E(x_t^2) = E(\exp(x_t+x_{t+h}))$ in my answer.  Actually I didn't suggest either of those statements in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the typos - it was late!  I corrected my answer.   You have $E(exp(x_t+x_{t+h}))=E(exp(x_t))E(exp(x_{t+h})=E(exp(x_t))^2$  Breaking up into a product requires independence.

Comment: I expanded my answer to include detailed development.  Suggest you check it - arithmetic is not my strong suit.

Comment: Ok, I will look at this a little deeper, but to be clear, I did not use the equation above, I simply substituted the new Normal rv created by adding $x_t + x_{t+h}$, which is still a normal rv, into the normal MGF.  I did not assume independence anywhere.

Comment: So I added my own solution below with calculations, I did not use your integration technique,  but I still think we are on the same track.  If you have any input would be appreciated.

Comment: I made an attempt to finish my derivation.  It looks messy. I got $A=\frac{e^Q}{G}$ where $G=2\pi(\lambda^2(0)-\lambda^2(h))$ and $Q=2\mu+2\lambda(0)(\lambda(0)+\lambda(h))(\lambda(0)-\lambda(h))^2$

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out so I'll answer my own question.

First we note the MGF for a normal rv $x$ with mean $\mu_x$ and variance $\sigma_x^2$ is
$$E[\exp(x\lambda)] = \exp\left[\mu_x \lambda + \frac{\sigma_x^2 \lambda^2}{2}\right]$$

so that $E[y_t] = E[\exp(x_t)]$ is the same as the normal MGF evaluated at $\lambda=1$, which implies that the mean function of $y_t$ is

$$E[y_t] = E[\exp(x_t)]= \exp\left[\mu_x + \frac{\gamma_x(0)}{2}\right]$$

Note that since $x_t$ and $x_{t+h}$ are identically distributed normal but not independent then the mean and variance of $x_t+x_{t+h}$ are

$$\mu_{x_t+x_{t+h}} = 2\mu_x$$

$$\sigma^2_{x_t+x_{t+h}} = \gamma_x(0) + \gamma_x(0) + 2\rho_x(h)\gamma_x(0) = 2\gamma_x(0)(1+\rho_x(h))$$

Thus the MGF for $x_t+x_{t+h}$ is

$$M_{x_t+x_{t+h}}(\lambda) = E[\exp(\lambda(x_t+x_{t+h}))] = \exp\left[2\mu_x \lambda + \gamma_x(0)(1+\rho_x(h))\lambda^2]\right]$$

By the same argument above using the MGF evaluated at $\lambda = 1$ we have

$$E[y_ty_{t+h}] = E[\exp(x_t+x_{t+h})] = M_{x_t+x_{t+h}}(1) = \exp\left[2\mu_x + \gamma_x(0)(1+\rho_x(h))]\right]$$
And we can calculate the autocovariance:

$$\gamma_y(h) = E[y_ty_{t+h}] - \mu_y^2 = \exp[2\mu_x + \gamma_x(0) + \gamma_x(0)\rho_x(h)] - \exp[2\mu_x +\gamma_x(0)]$$

$$=\exp[2\mu_x + \gamma_x(0)]\exp[\gamma_x(0)\rho_x(h)] - \exp[2\mu_x + \gamma_x(0)]$$

$$=\exp[2\mu_x + \gamma_x(0)]\left(\exp[\gamma_x(0)\rho_x(h)] - 1\right)$$

Comment: Wrong!  see my full answer.

Comment: I think it is corrected now, but still not totally sure.

Comment: My answer looks similar to yours, but there differences in detail.  Arithmetic has always been a problem for me.